# compare the current value with previous value of ajax success callback

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a Ajax request firing to a PHP DB script every 3 seconds
and i want to take decission on the based of returned result.
The result it is returning is a timestamp.
Consider the ajax request fired 2 times. I want to compare the first time result with second time. if they matched i want to do something, if they do not match i want to do some other thing.

```
success:function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
        }
```

I tried defining one other variable and put`msg` value in it to compare it with next `msg` value but that also changes same as `msg` value.

*How can i get both previous and next value at the same time so that i can compare them*

Comment: use `sets/maps`

Comment: so.... code that you have provided.... it does not work somehow?

Comment: @VladimirM what do you mean ?

Comment: @J4GD33P51NGH what I meant was that your code sample does not include any evidence of attempted solution. So I was wondering if you have more code you could share, so that the root cause of your issue could be identified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the result in a variable.

```
var prevResult;
$.ajax({
   ...
   success:function(msg){
       if (prevResult === msg) {
          ...
       }
       else {
          ...       
       }
       prevResult = msg;
   }
});
```

Comment: prevResult results in `undefined` at every new success call. its not working

Comment: It depends on where did you declare `prevResult`. If you put it just before the `ajax` call (like in my example) the variable is re-declared every 3 seconds, and therefore will be null. Put it in the first row of your js file, and check again.